# Tomcat container only starts interactively

Tags: docker

I'm a bit new to Docker, but I recently build a container running an old version of Docker and an even older version of JSPWiki (2.2.33 - yes, THAT old). This is in order to decommission an old VM that this is running on.

When I run the following command, my container launches interactively and then I can manually launch my tomcat application and navigate to the Wiki:

```
docker run -it -v wikifiles:/apps/wikifiles -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 wikitest:1.1 /bin/bash
```

When I just try to launch the container with the startup script, it fails...even though it's the same exact script.

```
docker run -it -v wikifiles:/apps/wikifiles -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 wikitest:1.1 /usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/bin/startup.sh
```

If I include `docker --log-level "debug" run ...` to see what's going on, I get:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.17
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.17
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
 EBU[0001] Error resize: Error response from daemon: bad file descriptor: unknown
 DEBU[0001] [hijack] End of stdout
 EBU[0001] Error resize: Error response from daemon: Container cbe278063c2389f2e3ad86ccb8944df5a600bb079d74e27e5a9cd1bb1e36ac2d is not running
```

I'm not even sure what to look at from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dan, the image wikitest:1.1 is not available. If it were possible to publish that, we could replay your issue and research on it.

Comment: Sorry...I've pushed it up and it's now at dcarrington/wikitest